# Scikit Learn Random forest classifier: How to produce a plot of OOB error against number of trees

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, random-forest

---

**Edit 2**:
There is now a lovely example in the [sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_ensemble_oob.html) on this.

---

In order to see how many trees are necessary in my forest, I'd like to plot the OOB error as the number of trees used in the forest is increased. I'm in `Python` using a `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier` but I can't find how to predict using a subset of trees in the forest. I could do this by making a new random forest on each iteration with increasing numbers of trees but this is too expensive.

It seems a similar task is possible with the Gradient Boosting object using the `staged_decision_function` method. See [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_regression.html).

This is quite a simple procedure in `R` and can be achieved by simply calling `plot(randomForestObject)`:
[image: Random Forest OOB error against Trees]

---

--**Edit**--
I see now the `RandomForestClassifier` object has an attribute `estimators_` which returns all the `DecisionTreeClassifier` objects in a list. So to solve this I can iterate through that list, predicting the results from each tree and taking a 'cumulative average'. However, is there really no easier way to do this already implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a discussion and code in this issue:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4273

You can add trees one-by-one like this:

```
n_estimators = 100
forest = RandomForestClassifier(warm_start=True, oob_score=True)

for i in range(1, n_estimators + 1):
    forest.set_params(n_estimators=i)
    forest.fit(X, y)
    print i, forest.oob_score_
```

The solution you propose also needs to get the oob indices for each tree, because you don't want to compute the score on all the training data.

I still feel this is a strange thing to do as the is really no natural ordering of the trees in the forest.
Can you explain what you use-case is? Do you want to find the minimum number of trees for a given accuracy to reduce prediction time? If you want fast prediction time, I'd suggest using GradientBoostingClassifier, which is usually much faster.

Comment: Though the number of trees isn't a tuning parameter, you do need to know how many trees you need for a stable solution. Producing this plot will give you a good idea about how many trees you need. Prediction time is not of concern, it's training time. When searching a large parameter space, knowing a good number of trees to use can make a big difference to the search time. `GradientBoostingClassifiers` are not parallelisable so not of use here.

Comment: If you search a large parameter space, the number of estimators you need for a stable solution will be different for each parameter setting. So how will this curve help?

Comment: I would use it before the parameter search to give a vague idea of the tree settings to search (I try a few of my grid search settings and produce this plot). Then once, the optimum parameters are found, I do it once more to check if I cant eek out any more performance by growing the forest a bit larger. It's also very useful to check to see how class performance changes (see rgb lines on my plot).

Comment: Given that it is the default plot method in `R`, I presume there are at least one or two people who also find this plot useful...I absolutely accept you points however.

Comment: I don't see any harm in adding it, if you like, though I can not guarantee a PR will be accepted. Maybe just as an example? It might be nice just for people transitioning from R to feel more at home.

Comment: As an example is just fine, I don't think there's any need to add it. It was useful, as a beginner, to see how to use the `warm_start` option. Many thanks.